# Batch file move files under/over certain file size

Tags: batch-file

I am relatively new to making batch files and while I found some examples of deleting files under a certain file size, I can't find one that simply moves them into a folder (at least not with a solution).
This is what I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Make fail Folder
md Fail

::Delete Files lower than minimum size
:: Size is in bytes
set "min.size=10000"

for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.*`) do If %%~zA LSS %min.size% del "%%A"
```

As you can see it makes a folder named "Fail" in the folder it is in, and this code deletes the files with a size under 10KB.

This script works quite well. The problem is, I do not want to delete the files, but move them to the newly created folder.
Can somebody provide assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `del "%%A"` with `move "%%A" .\fail\`

(assuming the `fail` directory is a subdirectory of the current directory as your code suggests)